# Display the status of selected modules of a specific job in Jenkins in one screen

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins, hudson, monitor

I would like to use Build Monitor Plugin but also displays the status and progress of selected **modules** of a specific job, In addition the the job's status.

I read the [Build monitior plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin) description and also explored the [Build Fauilre Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer) but none of them seem to have the ability to do I want.

Do you know any way or have any idea of displaying the builds' statuses of a job on the screen the way that the Build Monitor Plugin does to Jobs?

I would like it to look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Build Pipeline plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use latest version of Jenkins, you can make use of 'Blue ocean' plugin which was introduced few months ago. This does the similar job as build monitor page when a job is added as favorite ( Color changes based on job status)

Answer (score 1):

Adding Maven module support to the Jenkins Build Monitor plugin has been an [open issue](https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin/issues/60) since mid 2014.

Given that the most recent comment was in 2015 it doesn't look like it is actively being worked on.